# Multi-column problem

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, multicolumn

Consider the following table. First I have troubles to get the `multicolumn`-elements in the first row of the table limited to a maximum width (I tried it here with the command `C{0.75}` but obviously it does not work). The second issue: I would like to have the column-pair "orig." and "norm." centered to each of its `multicolumn`-elements.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\definecolor{LightGray}{gray}{.8}


\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}


\begin{table}[htbp]
   \centering
   \begin{tabular}{C{1.7cm}C{0.75cm}C{0.75cm}C{0.75cm}C{0.75cm}C{0.75cm}C{0.75cm}C{0.75cm}}

      \toprule
    &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{This is a long text for two rows} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{This is a long text for three rows} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{This is a long Text} \\

    \multirow{-2}{*}{Row 1} &
    org. & norm. &
    org. & norm. &
    org. & norm. &
    \multirow{-2}{*}{Result}\\

     \midrule

    1   &   0   &   0   &   1   &   0.14    &   7360    &   1   &   0.58    \\
    2   &   0.42    &   0.97    &   7   &   1   &   3420    &   0.46    &   0.85    \\
    3   &   0.42    &   0.97    &   7   &   1   &   3420    &   0.46    &   0.85    \\
    4   &   0.42    &   0.98    &   6   &   0.86    &   3610    &   0.49    &   0.80    \\
    5   &   0.43    &   0.99    &   6   &   0.86    &   4100    &   0.56    &   0.82    \\
    6   &   0.36    &   0.83    &   5   &   0.71    &   4280    &   0.58    &   0.71    \\
    7   &   0.36    &   0.83    &   5   &   0.71    &   4520    &   0.61    &   0.73    \\
    8   &   0.43    &   1   &   6   &   0.86    &   4000    &   0.54    &   0.82    \\
    9   &   0.27    &   0.63    &   3   &   0.43    &   3920    &   0.53    &   0.54    \\
    10  &   0.32    &   0.74    &   5   &   0.71    &   100 &   0.01    &   0.59    \\

      \bottomrule

   \end{tabular}
   \caption{caption}
   \label{tab:Example}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There has been another question on centering below `multicolumn` entries today, you might want to adapt my solution [solution given there](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59437/14697) (or maybe David's ;)). If the multicols still are too wide, try splitting them up into two rows. Moreover, you could make use of `booktab's` `\cmidrule` command to place spanner rules below the multicol headers (cf. `booktabs` manual or use search function). Last, the linked answer also shows number alignment with `siunitx`, which possibly is of interest, too.

Comment: @dgs: I tried to follow your approach but I failed installing the `tabu`-package (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59509/troubles-in-installing-package#59509).

Comment: Notwithstanding @egreg's update advice, you can use `tabularx` instead of `tabu`. Replace `\begin{tabu} spread 1em` by `\begin{tabularx}{.7\textwidth}`, accordingly change the `\end{...}` group too, and load `tabularx` instead of `tabu`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understood your question (in part because there are some references to *rows* that may actually be *columns*). Notice that I've chosen to dispense with the `\multirow` statements as they result in their arguments being place in somewhat odd locations (in my view, that is). I've also added some `\cmidrule` instructions in the header area of the table. Anyway, here's what I've come up with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow,booktabs,colortbl,tabularx}
\definecolor{LightGray}{gray}{.8}


\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
   \begin{tabular}{C{1.7cm} *{7}{C{0.75cm}} }
\toprule
    Column 1 &
    \multicolumn{2}{p{2cm}}{This is a long text for two columns} &
    \multicolumn{3}{p{3cm}}{This is a long text for three columns} &
    This is a long text & 
    Result\\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-6} \cmidrule(lr){7-7}
    &
    org. & norm. &
    org. & norm. &
    org. & norm. &\\
\midrule
  1   &   0   &   0   &   1   &   0.14        & 7360  &   1   &   0.58    \\        
  2   &   0.42    &   0.97    &   7   &   1   & 3420  & 0.46  &   0.85    \\        
  3   &   0.42    &   0.97    &   7   &   1   & 3420  & 0.46  &   0.85    \\         
  4   &   0.42    &   0.98    &   6   & 0.86  & 3610  & 0.49  &   0.80    \\        
  5   &   0.43    &   0.99    &   6   & 0.86  & 4100  & 0.56  &   0.82    \\        
  6   &   0.36    &   0.83    &   5   & 0.71  & 4280  & 0.58  &   0.71    \\        
  7   &   0.36    &   0.83    &   5   & 0.71  & 4520  & 0.61  &   0.73    \\        
  8   &   0.43    &   1   &   6   &   0.86    & 4000  & 0.54  &   0.82    \\        
  9   &   0.27    &   0.63    &   3   & 0.43  & 3920  & 0.53  &   0.54    \\        
  10  &   0.32    &   0.74    &   5   & 0.71  &  100  & 0.01  &   0.59    \\    
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
   \caption{caption}
   \label{tab:Example}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]