# Troubles in installing package

Tags: packages, installing

I'm using TeXShop (V 2.47) on my Mac (V 10.7.4) and tried to install the tabu-package but failed. Here is what I did:

1. Saved the tabu.dtx and tabu.ins file in my Donwloads-directory ([source for both files](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tabu))
2. Run tabu.ins in TeXShop.
3. After compilation several new files were generated in my Donwloads-directory, such as tabu.sty.
4. Run the following command in Terminal to open the directory, where I wanted to save the tabu.sty: open /usr/local/texlive/2010/

Now, the problem is, that I don't know where to copy the tabu.sty. I thought TeX Live Utility might be a tool for these kind of issues but running it (the first time) only produced a new problem:

2012-06-11 20:48:42 +0000 Notice -[TLMOperation main][11119]
tlmgr: package repository http://ctan.dcc.uchile.cl/systems/texlive/tlnet
The supported release as specified by the repository (2011)
does not match the release version of the installation (2010), bailing out.

Comment: First of all, you should consider to upgrade to MacTeX/TeX Live 2011 (but MacTeX/TeX Live 2012 is in the final stage before release, so you may want to wait for it). Look at [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58468/4427) and change `llncs` to `tabu` for a temporary installation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to place your file here:

```
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex
```

and then you need to run `sudo mktexlsr`.

But it's possible to place this file in your home:

```
~/Library/texmf/tex/latex
```

For me it's  `/Users/ego/Library/texmf/tex/latex`. This doesn't require anything else.

Be careful, if you update your distribution, the version of `tabu` inside your personal `texmf` is always used.